# Need a remove \" from image src in php

Tags: php, regex, fckeditor

I need to replace \" from image src.

I have one form and i use the FCK editor for Details and when i upload image and submit a form then after i get below value in post

```
<img scr="\"http://test.in/public/admin/uploadfiles/Lighthouse(2).jpg\"">
```

So i need to remove `\" from starting and \" from end` so its display properly to me.
I also try `ltrim() and strreplace()` but when i put some other things then it replace each place so i `need to replace it only in img scr must start and end \" only`

Any why to do this. I think this is possible using Regular expression but i have not enough knowledge for it.

Please suggest me any idea.

Comment: Instead of a hacky fix, why not solve the problem at its core? What's really causing the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable magic_quotes in your php config, then edit all your text where this error occurs to correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change the php.ini setting `magic_quotes_gpc = Off`.  If you can't do that, use `ini_set` in the php code itself.  If you can't do *that*, use `stripslashes` on the `$_POST` value you are getting.

Comment: I try to find this **magic_quotes_gpc** in cpanel but not getting can you suggest me where is this in cpanel

Comment: @Jalpesh do you have access to the php.ini file?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with what @Lee is saying however if you need to do it via a regular expression. This should do it.

```
<?php
    $pattern = '/\\\"/';
    $replacement =  '';
    $subject = '<img scr="\"http://test.in/public/admin/uploadfiles/Lighthouse(2).jpg\"">';
    $result = preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
?>
```

Comment: actually, that is a syntax error. you need  $replacement = '' ;

Answer (score 0):

using regexps, you could do it with the following:
to remove the first \", use

```
preg_replace('/<img scr=\"\\\/', '<img scr=', $your_string);
```

and then replace the second part with

```
preg_replace('/\\\\"\">/', '">', $your_string);
```